# Is an empty parenthesis a valid mathematical expression?

Tags: reference-request, notation

Is using an empty parenthesis valid?

For example, $15+()=15$.

What is the meaning if it is valid? I need an academic reference to validate this.

Comment: The meaning of mathematical notation is highly dependent on context. Which subfield(s) of mathematics are relevant to the case which interests you? And what is your motivation for the question: trying to interpret someone else's use of them, trying to justify using them yourself, trying to win a random bet, ...?

Answer (score 20):

We usually denote $n$-tuples in the form $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, so for example $(x,y,z)$ is a triple, $(x,y)$ is a pair, somewhat redundantly $(x)$ could be called a one-tuple and $()$ a (in fact: the) zero-tuple.

Comment: Then by "scalar addition", $15+()=()$, just as $15+(2,3,5)=(17,18,20)$.

Comment: Only if you identify $15$ with $(15,\dots,15)$ which may  or may not be appropriate depending on context. It also leads to questions such as what $(1,2) + (1,2,3)$ should be (which I could swear I've seen on math.se before)

Comment: @YvesDaoust “Scalar addition” is _horribly_ confusion-prone. Just because Matlab allows this kind of notation, doesn't mean it's a good idea to use it elsewhere.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I never said that it was a good thing, as I don't support delimiting tuples with parenthesis.

Answer (score 14):

Generally, no.

But you could say:

> Let us denote *something* with ().

... and start using (), if you think this would convey your point.

There is no need for academic reference validating this, it is the matter of *basic author freedom*.

Let's say you want to wear a violet tie with blue dots. You don't ask if there is a law permitting you to do this.

However, I would advise you not to use it, it creates confusion.

Answer (score 13):

We use parentheses to indicate the order of operations.

To refer to your example: the operator $+$ takes *two arguments*, in the form of $a+b$. You can think of $+$ as a function that takes two variables.

In this example, the $+$ is missing the second argument: there's nothing there. And $15 + $ isn't a valid mathematical statement -- it's not equal to anything, because the $+$ operation requires two variables.

An empty pair of parentheses thus doesn't really mean anything -- it just contains nothing. This destroys any equation it is placed inside -- because $()$ is just *nothing*, not even $0$, and mathematical operations aren't defined on *nothing*.

Comment: Recommend changing "variable" -> "value". (15 is not a variable, for example)

Comment: @DavidBalažic It's in the context of functions. We usually say that functions take *variables* rather than *values*. Also, I could argue that 15 is the variable that takes the value 15. ;-)

Comment: In some contexts, a partial application like $15+$ is taken to mean $\lambda x.\ 15+x$.

Comment: @askyle sure, but partial application presumes the existence of that second argument. (I'm thinking about e.g. Haskell.) When we call a function like that, the call *requires* that second argument, so it is valid upon execution.

Comment: @Newb That doesn't contradict the fact that the expression $15+$ (or `(15+)` in proper Haskell) has a well-defined denotation in that context, even if you never actually call that function later.

Comment: @askyle That's a fair point. In answering this question, I was not thinking about Programming Languages. I was only considering $15+()$ in algebraic terms.

Answer (score 5):

It's certainly not conventional, and it's hard to think of any occasion when one might want to use such notation explicitly. That said, it would not be illogical to define () as zero, just as the empty set is sometimes written $\{\}$. As a precedent, an empty sum, such as $\sum_{k=1}^0x_k$, is defined to be zero by a standard convention.

Comment: Good point on the zero sum.

Comment: @Newb: yep, but what about $5\times()$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's called the empty product, and it's also by convention equal to $1$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Comment: @Newb: Perfect, then $()=0=1$.

Comment: @Newb: You can consistently define the empty sum to be $0$ while the empty product is $1$. Also, you can consistently define () to be an empty sum, or you can consistently define it to be an empty product; but you cannot consistently define () to be an empty sum and an empty product.

Answer (score 4):

Anything is valid *if you define it*. Mathematicians tend to not only use different notation for the same thing, but often the same notation to denote different things. That's all right as long as they define up front what a given notation is supposed to mean. In many cases, the meaning is so commonplace that all mathematicians agree upon it. You'd find no serious debates on what $3+4$ could possibly mean.

But for other notation, things soon get far less obvious. What is $ab$? It could be the variable $a$ multiplied by the variable $b$. It could be a monomial in a multivariate polynomial ring over the indeterminates $a$ and $b$ (and perhaps others). It could be the composition of two functions, i.e. what you get if you first apply $b$ and then $a$. It could be the concatenation of words. It could be a hundred other things, and often the lines between these concepts are quite blurry, so it could be many of these things at once. So unless the intended meaning of such a notation is clear from context, the author should clarify it using a definition, lest his formulas become ambiguous.

In your case, there is no universally agreed meaning for $()$ which would make sense in a context of addition. Parentheses are used for very many things in mathematics, among them the ordering of operations Newb indicated and the collection of tuples Hagen mentioned. But for operation ordering, an empty expression inside the parentheses makes no sense, while for tuples you'd have to clarify what meaning you attach to the plus sign if the operands are as you stated them. The comment by Yves gives one possible and sensible interpretation, but taken together the interpretation is more like guessing what this could possibly mean, and notation which relies on this kind of guesswork is bad notation.

Answer (score 2):

In [mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic), and computer programming languages like [Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892570/what-is-in-haskell-exactly), [F#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483472.aspx), [OCaml](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/basics.html), and [Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539822/whats-the-difference-between-unit-and-nothing), `()` represents the (single possible) value of the [`Unit` type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type), which is used to denote a function that returns no value.

It is not valid to add a number with this representation of `()`.

Comment: Not sure how it works with mathematical logic, but in Haskell and Scala () is simply a built-in type that is inhabited by [only, discounting bottom] the value (). Nonterminating (or otherwise erroneous, such as division by 0) expressions are denoted by the bottom value, which inhabits all types.

Comment: @Cubic Thanks. I don't think you're 100% correct: the Scala bottom type, `Nothing`, is not a valid type for this function: `def r(): Nothing = { 5 / 0 }`. I will update my answer a bit, and we'll see if we can find the truth.

Comment: Jacob: You're misunderstanding Scalas Nothing type; Nothing is a subtype of every other type, not the other way round. So a value of type `Nothing` can be assigned to a variable of any other type, i.e. `val x: Int = ???` (??? is a predefined method of type `Nothing` in [scala.Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/#scala.Predef$).

Comment: ^- of course there are no values of type Nothing, but _expressions_ can have that type. There's also `scala.Null`, which is the type of the `null` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Notation is based on common acknowledgement. Sure you can invent any random thing, for example you can even draw a monkey instead of parenthesis. But this makes people confused about the notation.

If here you mean a variable, usually people put a letter here. When the letters are not used up (or not for a specific purpose, eg. Greek letter for angle, an object usually denoted by a specific letter), put a Latin letter makes most sense. $x$ usually means an unknown.

Back to the case in your question. From my previous context, I assume you want to put a variable or an unknown there. But after I posted, I suddenly came up with an idea that what if you mean $0$ by $()$? Because why not?

Comment: Because we already have a notation for $0$.